# Jhipster import-jdl controlling what gets generated

Tags: jhipster, jdl

I have a simple JHipster JDL file that looks like below

```
entity Student {
  name String, 
  age Integer
}
```

and I have this saved in a file called student.jh

Now I am trying to make use of the JHipster CLI and generate the entities needed for my dummy project. I noticed that by default JHipster ends up generating the following:

- Entity classes
- DTO classes
- Repository classes
- Service classes (I think this we can further customise by adding options as to whether we need service implementation as well)
- Rest Controllers
- Integration tests
- Gatling tests (This I believe is configurable)

I was hoping to know if I could have JHipster skip generating the rest controllers because I would like to add custom rest controllers by hand. I know that I could merely have these controllers alone deleted (along with the Integration Tests that also get generated).

Is there any way in which this can be controlled? I have tried using all of the cli options for `jhipster import-jdl` but no luck yet.

here's the command I am using

```
jhipster import-jdl src/main/resources/student.jh
```

Here's the complete output

```
jhipster -d import-jdl src/main/resources/student.jh
INFO! Using JHipster version installed globally
DEBUG!  Executing CLI only script
DEBUG!  cmd: import-jdl from ./import-jdl
DEBUG!  args: [object Undefined]
INFO! Executing import-jdl src/main/resources/student.jh
DEBUG!  Options: debug: true, skip-install: false, interactive: false, json-only: false, ignore-application: false, ignore-deployments: false, skip-ui-grouping: false, skip-db-changelog: false, skip-sample-repository: false, skipInstall: false, jsonOnly: false, ignoreApplication: false, ignoreDeployments: false, skipUiGrouping: false, skipDbChangelog: false, skipSampleRepository: false, from-cli: true, fromCli: true, inline:
DEBUG!  JDLProcessor started with files: src/main/resources/student.jh and options: debug: true, skip-install: false, interactive: false, json-only: false, ignore-application: false, ignore-deployments: false, skip-ui-grouping: false, skip-db-changelog: false, skip-sample-repository: false, skipInstall: false, jsonOnly: false, ignoreApplication: false, ignoreDeployments: false, skipUiGrouping: false, skipDbChangelog: false, skipSampleRepository: false, from-cli: true, fromCli: true
INFO! Found .yo-rc.json on path. This is an existing app
INFO! The JDL is being parsed.
DEBUG!  importState exportedEntities: 1
DEBUG!  importState exportedApplications: 0
DEBUG!  importState exportedDeployments: 0
INFO! Found entities: Student.
INFO! The JDL has been successfully parsed
DEBUG!  Applications not generated
INFO! Generating 1 entity.
DEBUG! Generator is starting

Found the .jhipster/Student.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!


The entity Student is being updated.

DEBUG! Generator is starting
DEBUG! Time taken to write files: 62ms
   create src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/20210202113651_added_entity_Student.xml
   create src/main/resources/config/liquibase/fake-data/student.csv
   create src/main/java/org/rationaleemotions/domain/Student.java
   create src/main/java/org/rationaleemotions/web/rest/StudentResource.java
   create src/main/java/org/rationaleemotions/repository/search/StudentSearchRepository.java
   create src/main/java/org/rationaleemotions/repository/StudentRepository.java
   create src/test/java/org/rationaleemotions/web/rest/StudentResourceIT.java
   create src/test/java/org/rationaleemotions/repository/search/StudentSearchRepositoryMockConfiguration.java
   create src/test/java/org/rationaleemotions/domain/StudentTest.java
    force src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml
DEBUG! Generator has ended
DEBUG! Generator has ended
DEBUG!  Deployments not generated
INFO! Congratulations, JHipster execution is complete!
```

Below is the complete output of my JHipster info command

```
jhipster info
INFO! Using JHipster version installed globally
INFO! Executing jhipster:info
Welcome to the JHipster Information Sub-Generator

##### **JHipster Version(s)**

##### **JHipster configuration, a `.yo-rc.json` file generated in the root folder**


<details>
<summary>.yo-rc.json file</summary>
<pre>
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "org.rationaleemotions"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "6.10.5",
    "applicationType": "microservice",
    "baseName": "necropolis",
    "packageName": "org.rationaleemotions",
    "packageFolder": "org/rationaleemotions",
    "serverPort": "8081",
    "authenticationType": "oauth2",
    "cacheProvider": "hazelcast",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mariadb",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mariadb",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "eureka",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "YourJWTSecretKeyWasReplacedByThisMeaninglessTextByTheJHipsterInfoCommandForObviousSecurityReasons",
    "embeddableLaunchScript": false,
    "creationTimestamp": 1611077969383,
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "otherModules": [],
    "enableTranslation": false,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "blueprints": [],
    "skipClient": true,
    "skipUserManagement": true
  }
}

</pre>
</details>


##### **JDL for the Entity configuration(s) `entityName.json` files generated in the `.jhipster` directory**

<details>
<summary>JDL entity definitions</summary>

<pre>
entity Student {
  name String,
  age Integer
}
microservice Student with necropolis
clientRootFolder Student with necropolis

</pre>
</details>


##### **Environment and Tools**

openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)

git version 2.30.0

node: v14.15.3

yeoman: 3.1.1

Docker version 20.10.0, build 7287ab3

docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192

identical .jhipster/Student.json
INFO! Congratulations, JHipster execution is complete!
```